# Dotnetnuke Braintree - XMLHttpRequest cannot load transparent redirect

Tags: dotnetnuke, braintree

I'm trying to develop a braintree payment gateway (transparent redirect) on my dotnetnuke website and while I was developing on development site with http development everything worked. When i put my code in the production website with https, i have this error on my chrome console and not works!

[image]

After some search i put this on my web.config:

```
<httpProtocol> 
    <customHeaders> 
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> 
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" /> 
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" /> 
    </customHeaders> 
</httpProtocol>
```

And my payment still works and a receive the transparent url:

```
<--urlbase-->?http_status=200&id=xxx&kind=create_transaction&hash=xxx
```

But when execute:

```
Result<Transaction> chargeResult = this.BraintreeGateway().TransparentRedirect.ConfirmTransaction(this.Request.Url.Query);
```

Nothing happens! I don't have errors in the event viewer!

Comment: Full Disclosure: I work for Braintree. Braintree's "Transparent Redirect" integration method has been deprecated. It does not receive new features, and is no longer fully supported. Braintree recommends using [the newest version of Braintree's javascript library](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3). If you're using WebForms, you can [reference this example integration](https://gist.github.com/jclementi/c3bed1e9ab4e950dcbdb3f20ccc752e1). To get more involved help, please reach out to [Braintree Support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).